# What size of a solar sail would you need to overcome orbital decay?

Tags: solar-sail, station-keeping, orbital-decay

Specifics of the question:

- Placed into a 400km 0 inclination orbit
- 10 kg 20cm cube
- Able to orient itself in any direction

Let’s say we want this satellite to be able to indefinitely orbit earth. This is of course impossible because eventually it would break, but ignoring that how big of a solar sail would we need to overcome orbital decay to achieve this?

Comment: The answers here suggest 400km is below the limit for any sized sail to be useful due to drag increasing faster than thrust [Can solar sail prevent orbital decay?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/can-solar-sail-prevent-orbital-decay)

Comment: @GremlinWranger ah, I’m not sure why I didn’t see that question. Thank you.