# Could the International Space Station be fitted with solar sails?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, solar-power, solar-sail, reboost

How much solar sail and vane surface area would be needed to replace the boosts needed to keep the ISS in orbit? Could this be done at a higher orbit minimizing atmospheric drag?

[What is the closest to Earth you can expect lift from a solar sail?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/951/what-is-the-closest-to-earth-you-can-expect-lift-from-a-solar-sail?rq=1)

Comment: Try to calculate the necessary size. How much time of an orbit the sails would deliver a useful force to the right direction for lifting the orbit? Would the force of the solar sails be substantialy bigger than the increased drag caused by the sails?

Comment: @Uwe thanks. I believe that with certain angles in the sail shadows overlapping canceling radiation pressure a certain angles in relation to the sun and the right orbit that a modified solar sails can be made to always have orbital stability? A mast would be needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ignoring the ISS, the question is simply whether light pressure on the sail can counteract the drag on the sail from atmosphere. Light pressure near Earth is about $10 \mu Pa$ (with optimum geometry and no eclipse). So the question is what is the drag force per square meter of sail. We [know](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12631/what-is-the-iss-drag) that the ISS experiences about 0.2N of drag, and its area is dominated by the solar panels at around $2500 m^2$ suggesting a drag pressure in the vicinity of $80 \mu Pa$ at that altitude. So any sail will add more drag than boost.

Comment: Interestingly this basically says that solar sails are useless in general  (at least to lift your orbit) until you are some way above the ISS altitude.

Comment: What if it boosted to a higher orbit then which to solar sail would be deployed?

Comment: @muze see one of the 4 existing questions about why thats not a useful idea. A LEO space station is easy access- go much further than that and you need much more deltaV to rendevouz.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I understand now

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn but I am not convened that a hybrid diamagnetic solar sail couldn't do where a solar sail alone could.

Comment: @MuzethegoodTroll. If it boosted to a higher orbit it might no longer be as well shielded from radiation. (I understand that it is below the lower vanAllen belt).