# Would adding a long pole to the International Space Station keep it from tumbling via gravity gradient stabilization?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, materials, stability

What things can be done mechanically to make the ISS more stable in a dormant state [without a crew](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31287/how-would-the-international-space-station-be-maintained-unmanned)?
I have listed a couple of links that may work, but I am open for constructive criticism and new ideas.

- [What is the straightest, longest and strongest pole?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/which-is-the-best-extendable-pole)
- [How would a long pole be transported to space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30972/how-would-a-long-pole-be-transported-to-space)
- [Could the International Space Station be fitted with solar sails?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31342/could-the-international-space-station-be-fitted-with-solar-sails)
- [What is the closest to Earth you can expect lift from a solar sail?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/951/what-is-the-closest-to-earth-you-can-expect-lift-from-a-solar-sail)

Comment: The crew have nothing to do with keeping the ISS stable, it's all automatic.

Comment: @GdD https://www.space.com/42156-soyuz-abort-close-call-space-policy-leroy-chiao-opinion.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a long pole to the station (particularly with sufficient mass on the end) will increase the station's moment of inertia.  This will reduce the effect that a perturbation will have on the station's attitude.  However, it also makes it more difficult to correct an error in the attitude.

The reaction wheels that are already on the station are a better solution.

Comment: How does gravity gradient play into this?

Comment: The pole itself would not have extra mass at the end. It would have solar vanes.

Comment: @Muze Which presumably have some mass.

Comment: If you want to comment on this in an informed way you should look up the subject. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity-gradient_stabilization  Leaving this effect out makes your answer useless.

Comment: @OrganicMarble is correct, other then stabilizing the pole with solar vanes the pole would stay vertical because of the gravity gradient of Earth. I'm sorry for presuming that was given and should have included it.

Comment: The ISS has Control Moment Gyroscopes, not reaction wheels.